# DBeaver not exporting all records

Tags: export, dbeaver

I am trying to export more than 200 records from DBeaver Community to a CSV.  I have no idea how to do this in the Export Wizard.  I know I can change the onscreen dataset size, but sure there must be a way of defaulting the export to ALL RECORDS?

Thanks